# Apple iPhone 6 Plus display languages

Tags: iphone

I want to buy an iPhone, and would like to ask whether the iPhone 6 Plus has either Persian or Farsi language support.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple eventually added](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-41355541) the Persian keyboard and language to the list of the iPhone keyboards and preferred languages back in 2017. Now all iPhones with iOS 11+ can add Persian keyboard and or language in their iPhone `Settings > General > Keyboards` or `.. > Language & Region`.

Prior to iOS 11, Persian users could install the Arabic keyboard and long-press ک - ج - ب - ز - ي keys to input the Persian letters گ - چ - پ - ژ - ی.